# BibLaTeX – idem and \autocite + \autocites

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex with the `verbose-trad1` style and mixing the `\autocite`  and `\autocites` commands as necessary.

However, when the same reference is used in an `\autocites` following an `\autocite`, it is not shortened to *Ibid.* as it should be, but *Idem, Work title* is used instead. For example:

```
Text text\autocite[p.10]{Smith} text text\autocites[p.20]{Smith}[p.100]{Jones} text...
```

Will produce:

```
1) Smith, Work title, p.10.
2) Idem, Work title, p.20; Jones, Other title, p.100.
```

Instead of:

```
1) Smith, Work title, p.10.
2) Ibid., p.20; Jones, Other title, p.100.
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load biblatex with `style=verbose-trad1,ibidtracker=context`.

The default setting for this style is `ibidtracker=constrict`, which combines the `context` and `strict` settings. Under `context` recurrent citations are tracked separately between the body text and footnotes. The `strict` setting avoids potentially ambiguous *ibidem* references, such as those occurring in or following a citation list.

This information can be found in description for `ibidtracker` in the list of internal preamble options from the biblatex manual's User Guide.